# clustering simple sequences

Tags: clustering

I have a simple question. I have a vector that has only 0/1 values.
I want to count the number of sequences that are larger than some number. For example, find out how many times I have a run of three ones (1,1,1) or more.

Any smart idea how to do that?

Thank you,
Nitzan.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't clustering: no statistical analysis involved.

Second, the obvious algorithm is already O(n) and I don't think you want to look into approximation or SIMD optimization.

Just process one item at a time: does it continue the current run, or start a new run.